# What's Chrome doing if I'm signed in but have syncing off?

Tags: google-chrome

Chrome 80 automatically signs me in to the browser when I visit Gmail and log in there. I don't have a problem with this but I'm not interested in syncing my data (bookmarks, history, etc.) across devices, so I've kept syncing off.

What's Chrome doing in this case (being signed in but with syncing off)? Is there any reason I should stay signed in? Is it going to enhance my experience somehow? Is it send more data to Google? Just interested in what's happening under the hood.

Comment: Are you 100% you are actually logged into your Google Account in Google Chrome?  I use Chrome daily at work, I am logged into my Google Account, and I don't have the same issues.  My Google profile might contain my name but I am not actually logged into my account within Google Chrome.  *Verify Chrome actually indicates your email.*  Likewise is this new behavior you just discovered?

Comment: Hi @Ramhound, yes, I'm 100% for sure logged in to Chrome with my Google account :) It has my Gmail address and account avatar and everything. I think it's new behavior, maybe as of Chrome 80? There's a way to turn it on off in the preferences (see "Allow Chrome sign in"). I don't necessarily want to turn it off, though, I'm just wondering what the purpose of logging in is if I'm not planning on using syncing.